# Summarizing several percentages of uneven sample sizes

Tags: percentages, means

We are comparing the prevalence of a trait across 40 depth bins in the ocean. The notable part is that the percentage of organisms with this trait is nearly the same (80%) across all depth bins, despite different total counts and diversity of entities. My question is how to summarize these percentages and show the low variability of this value across the depths. We are not as interested in a multiple comparison / null hypothesis test, as I have found those. It feels wrong to average and derive standard deviation for percentages. The total count of data points is around 480k, but N can be a couple orders of magnitude different between bins, so the ratio we are comparing could be 8/10 or 8000/10000. 
(I would like to migrate this from cross validated but not sure how.)